# google one tap sign in not working on subdomain domain in react app

Tags: reactjs, google-identity, google-one-tap

I have implemented google one tap sign-in in my react app following steps in [Google one tap Web](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid).

Below is the code:

```
 import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getGoogleClientId } from './helpers';

const OneTapSignIn = () => {
  const script = useScript('https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const scriptFlag = '__googleOneTapScript__';
  const handleCredentialResponse = response => {
    if (response.credential) {
     // Use Id token here.
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window !== undefined && script === 'ready') {
      window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: getGoogleClientId(),
        callback: data => handleCredentialResponse(data),
      });
      window[scriptFlag] = true;
    }
    if (window[scriptFlag] && script === 'ready') {
      dispatch(hideAddtoHome());
      window.google.accounts.id.prompt(notification => {
        // Check if google prompt is closed.
        if (notification.isSkippedMoment()) {
        }
      });
    }
  }, [script]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {/* <div
        id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id=""
        data-callback={handleCredentialResponse}>
      </div> */}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default OneTapSignIn;
```

This is working as expected and showing prompt on my local environment, but nothing shows up in the DEVELOPMENT Environment. I have added my dev environment domain on google account as instructed in the documentation:

> If your project doesn't have a Web application-type client ID, click
> Create credentials > OAuth client ID to create one. Be sure to include
> your site's domain in the Authorized JavaScript origins box. Please
> note that Google One Tap can only be displayed in HTTPS domains. When
> you perform local tests or development, you must add both
> http://localhost and http://localhost:<port_number> to the Authorized
> JavaScript origins box.

My dev url is something like: https://dev.example.com

**UPDATE:**

As per [Display one tap across subdomains](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/subdomains) we need to add **"data-state_cookie_domain"** attribute in html code of one tap prompt but in my case as you can see above I am using JS code for displaying one tap prompt how can this be added in JS code?

**Update:**
I added state_cookie_domain:

```
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: getGoogleClientId(),
            callback: data => handleCredentialResponse(data),
            state_cookie_domain: 'https://example.com'
          });
```

but this did not solve the problem, still not triggering code for google one tap.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:<port>` in [Google Console API for your application](https://console.developers.google.com/apis)

Note: I think you just need to drop the `https://` from `state_cookie_domain`